# Check if a string holding Date contains time

Tags: c#, .net

How can I check if a C# string variable holding a Date value contains time portion?

```
string date="2013-04-03 10:15:00";
string date="2013-04-03";
```

Comment: The last one contains time part as well. It's 00:00 (midnight)

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, and where the values come from. If you can rely on the format of these strings being precise, and there isn't a possibility of different regional date/time formats being used, then simple string based checks can be used (perhaps even just check if length is 10), otherwise you'll need to parse to DateTime and check using that (hours, minutes, seconds, ms all equal 0)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have always have same format You can [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) the string and check the `Length` of returned array.

```
if(date.Split(' ').Length > 1)
{
   //String contains date and time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
if (date.Contains(":"))
{
}
```

Comment: So `"::::::::"` is a `DateTime` value?

Comment: The OP says `if a C# string variable holding a Date value`

Answer (score 0):

I think a more important question to consider is this:  Why do you need to know?  Is it so you can add a default value for the time, or is the time not relevant to your problem?  Either way, Parsing the date using a standard method should fit the bill:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

For example:

```
bool IsDefaultTime(string parseTime)
{
    DateTime date;
    //parse the date and see if we have a time element
    if(DateTime.TryParse(parseTime, out date))
    {
        //returns true when the time is midnight.
        return date.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Value was not in recognized datetime     format: {0}", parseTime));
}
```

Other than that, if you are looking for an efficient check, and can ensure that a date will always be in the format you described above, (i.e. MM-dd-yyyy) then you could just check the length of the string:

```
bool HasTimeElement(string parseTime)
{
   //Ignoring all validation concerns to be handled elsewhere.
   return parseTime.Length > 10;
}
```